# My ArrayList shows empty when looping throug Object.keys

Tags: javascript, reactjs, object, html-table

I am trying to create Simple Table with react.I am importing CustomerList and then looping  through all the Object.keys to get the table header first and then the body part.
When console logging I can see all my **customerList** properties are there but when console.loging the **Object.keys** it shows 'undefined', I don't understand where I am making the silly mistake. 
Will be gratefull for all the help I can get.
Thanks in Advance!

I have tried Google and youtube but not getting the answer I am looking for

```
export const customerList = [
    {
        name: "Anny Larsson",
        age: 23,
        id: 1,
        title: "Title1",
        accountNumber: "12345",
        address: "Stockholm 14, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList:["coding", "writing", "reading", "skiing"],
        emptyColumn: ""
    },
    {
        name: "Helena hel",
        age: 20,
        id:2,
        title: "Title2",
        accountNumber: "22245",
        address: "Stockholm City, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList:["coding", "Cooking", "games", "skiing"],
        emptyColumn: ""

    },
    {
        name: "Ayesha AAA",
        age: 25,
        id: 3,
        title: "Title3",
        accountNumber: "09845",
        address: "Stockholm 21, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList:["coding", "Cooking", "games", "skiing"],
        emptyColumn: ""
    },
   //more list goes here......
     // ...............
];

export default customerList;
```

```
// My customerListTable.js

import React, { Component } from 'react';   
import CustomerList from './CustomerList';
import CustomerTitle from './CustomerTitle';



class CustomerListTable extends Component {
        state = { 
            customerList: CustomerList 
         }

    componentDidMount(){
        this.setState({
            customerList: [...this.state.customerList] //copying the list
        })
    };


    headerTitle = Object.keys(this.state.customerList[0]).map((header , index) => {
        console.log("columnHeaderTitles ", this.headerTitle )
        // return (
        //     <li>{header}</li>
        // )    
    })

    render() { 

        console.log("customer list", this.state.customerList)
        console.log("table header", this. headerTitle);

        return ( 
            <div>
                <h1>Customer table....</h1>
                <div> 
                 <CustomerTitle />

                 <table>
                     <thead>
                         <tr>
                            <th>{this.headerTitle}</th>

                         </tr>
                     </thead>


                     <tbody>

                     </tbody>
                 </table>

                </div>

            </div>
         );
    }
}

export default CustomerListTable;
```

[image]

Comment: You need to `return` a value from your `.map()` method to specify what you replace the current element. Since you're not returning anything it's replacing each element with `undefined`

Comment: Thanks for the help, Much Appreciated, I have one small things to ask and that is to do with CSS styling: I have styled the table header and the body and I want the name should be under tableheader name and age should be under tableheader age and so on, but right know my table body doesnot goes alone with the table header, Will appreciate your help with this. the code can be found here : https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-dynamic-table-with-sorting-img48

Answer (score 1):

```js
const customerList = [
    {
        name: "Anny Larsson",
        age: 23,
        id: 1,
        title: "Title1",
        accountNumber: "12345",
        address: "Stockholm 14, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList:["coding", "writing", "reading", "skiing"],
        emptyColumn: ""
    }
];
const headerTitle = Object.keys(customerList[0]).map((header , index) => header)
console.log(headerTitle)
```

In `Thead Table`, map `headerTitle` to create dynamic `th`:

```
<thead>
    <tr>
    {
       this.headerTitle.map((item, index) => <th key={index}>{item}</th>)        
    }
    </tr>
</thead>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you are overcomplicating your logic, but your code seems to work.
Only returning something inside your map function adds the headers to the component:

```js
const CustomerList = [
    {
        name: "Anny Larsson",
        age: 23,
        id: 1,
        title: "Title1",
        accountNumber: "12345",
        address: "Stockholm 14, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList: [
            "coding", "writing", "reading", "skiing"
        ],
        emptyColumn: ""
    }, {
        name: "Helena hel",
        age: 20,
        id: 2,
        title: "Title2",
        accountNumber: "22245",
        address: "Stockholm City, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList: [
            "coding", "Cooking", "games", "skiing"
        ],
        emptyColumn: ""

    }, {
        name: "Ayesha AAA",
        age: 25,
        id: 3,
        title: "Title3",
        accountNumber: "09845",
        address: "Stockholm 21, Stockholm Sweden",
        hobbyList: [
            "coding", "Cooking", "games", "skiing"
        ],
        emptyColumn: ""
    }
];

class CustomerListTable extends React.Component {
    state = {
        customerList: CustomerList
    }
    
    headerTitle = Object.keys(this.state.customerList[0]).map((header) => {
        return (<li key={header}>{header}</li>)
    })

    render() {
        return (<div>
            <h1>Customer table....</h1>
            <div>

                <table>
                    <thead>
                        <tr>
                            <th>{this.headerTitle}</th>

                        </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody></tbody>
                </table>

            </div>

        </div>);
    }
}

ReactDOM.render(<CustomerListTable/>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, Much Appreciated, I have one small things to ask and that is to do with CSS styling: I have styled the table header and the body and I want the name should be under tableheader name and age should be under tableheader age and so on, but right know my table body doesnot goes alone with the table header, Will appreciate your help with this. the code can be found here : https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-dynamic-table-with-sorting-img48

Comment: @Ayesha Not a CSS problem I think: you have you `thead` inside of your `tbody`, they should be siblings.

Comment: Hi again, isit OK if I ask you one more question,  I have created a delete function which will delete the whole row when clicked on the 'delete' button, and it seems to be working. but in console log it shows undefined ( the row which is deleted is undefined) , I dont get it why it show undefined instead of showing the row name which is deleted. here is my code :  https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-dynamic-table-with-sorting-img48

Comment: You function works fine, it is just that you are trying to log a property of the state that doesn't exist: `filteredRows`. You are not storing the row that is deleted in your `onDelete` method. As an example, I have modified your code to store the last deleted item and restore it by pressing Ctrl+z

Comment: Here: https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-react-dynamic-table-with-sorting-hown6